# Can't load JS into WebView in Swift

Tags: javascript, xcode, macos, swift, webview

I'm trying to inject JavaScript into a web page I'm loading with WebView. I got as far as this:

```
override func webView(sender: WebView!, didClearWindowObject windowObject: WebScriptObject!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    if (webView.mainFrameDocument != nil) { // && frame.DOMDocument == webView.mainFrameDocument) {
        let document:DOMDocument = webView.mainFrameDocument
        let hangoutsMode: String? = Preferences.getString("hangoutsMode")
        let windowScriptObject = webView.windowScriptObject;
        windowScriptObject.setValue(self, forKey: "gInbox")
        windowScriptObject.evaluateWebScript("console = { log: function(msg) { gInbox.consoleLog(msg); } }")

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("gInboxTweaks", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "Assets")
        let jsString = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        let script = document.createElement("script")
        let jsText = document.createTextNode(jsString)
        let bodyEl = document.getElementsByName("body").item(0)

        script.setAttribute("type", value: "text/javascript")
        script.appendChild(jsText)
        bodyEl?.appendChild(script)

        windowScriptObject.evaluateWebScript(String(format: "console.log('test'); hangoutsMode(%@)", hangoutsMode!))
    }
}
```

Which worked in objective C, but no longer in Swift. I'm not sure where it goes wrong exactly, but it can't find the `bodyEl` and it remains nil. I tried modifying (or completely removing) the `if` on the outside of it, but nothing.